# python 3 asyncio and MotorClient: how to use motor with multithreading and multiple event loops

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, tornado-motor, pymongo-3.x

I am back with a question about asyncio. I find it very useful (especially due to the GIL with threads) and I am trying to boost performances of some pieces of code.

My application is doing the following:

- 1 Background daemon thread "A" receives events from connected clients and reacts by populating a SetQueue (that simply is an event queue that removes duplicate ids) and by doing some insertions in a DB. I get this daemon from another module (basically I control a callback from when an event is received). In my sample code below I substituted this with a thread I generate and that very simply just populates the queue with 20 items and mimics DB inserts before exiting.
- 1 Background daemon thread "B" is launched (loop_start) and he just loops over running until completion a coroutine that:

  - Fetches all the items in the queue (if not empty, otherwise it release the control for x seconds and then the coroutine is re-launched)
  - For each id in the queue it launches a chained coroutine that:

    - Creates and waits for a task that just fetches all relevant information for that id from the DB. I am using MotorClient that supports asyncio to do await in the task itself.
    - Uses an Pool of Processes executor to launch a process per id that uses the DB data to do some CPU intensive processing.
- The main thread just initializes the db_client and takes loop_start and stop commands.

That is basically it.

Now I am trying to boost performance as much as possible.

My current issue is in using `motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncioMotorClient()` in this way:

1. It gets initialized in the main thread and there I want to create indexes
2. Thread "A" needs to perform DB insertions
3. Thread "B" needs to perform DB finds/reads

How can I do this? Motor states that it is meant for a single thread application where you use obviously a single event loop.
Here I found myself forced to have two events loops, one in thread "A" and one in thread "B". This is not optimal, but I didn't manage to use a single event loop with call_soon_threadsafe while keeping the same behavior...and I think performance wise I am still gaining much with two events loop that release control over the gil bound cpu core.

Should I use three different AsyncioMotorClient instances (one per thread) and use them as stated above? I failed with different errors while trying.

Here is my sample code that doesn't include just the the MotorClient initialization in Asynchro's `__init__`

```
import threading
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import functools
import os
import time
import logging
from random import randint
from queue import Queue





# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('{}.log'.format(__name__))
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(processName)s - %(threadName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)


class SetQueue(Queue):
    """Queue that avoids duplicate entries while keeping an order."""
    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.queue = set()

    def _put(self, item):
        if type(item) is not int:
            raise TypeError
        self.queue.add(item)

    def _get(self):
        # Get always all items in a thread-safe manner
        ret = self.queue.copy()
        self.queue.clear()
        return ret


class Asynchro:
    def __init__(self, event_queue):
        self.__daemon = None
        self.__daemon_terminate = False
        self.__queue = event_queue

    def fake_populate(self, size):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, args=(size,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def worker(self, size):
        run = True
        populate_event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(populate_event_loop)
        cors = [self.worker_cor(i, populate_event_loop) for i in range(size)]
        done, pending = populate_event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(cors))
        logger.debug('Finished to populate event queue with result done={}, pending={}.'.format(done, pending))
        while run:
            # Keep it alive to simulate something still alive (minor traffic)
            time.sleep(5)
            rand = randint(100, 200)
            populate_event_loop.run_until_complete(self.worker_cor(rand, populate_event_loop))
            if self.__daemon_terminate:
                logger.debug('Closed the populate_event_loop.')
                populate_event_loop.close()
                run = False

    async def worker_cor(self, i, loop):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.__queue.put(i)
        logger.debug('Wrote {} in the event queue that has now size {}.'.format(i, self.__queue.qsize()))
        # Launch fake DB Insertions
        #db_task = loop.create_task(self.fake_db_insert(i))
        db_data = await self.fake_db_insert(i)
        logger.info('Finished to populate with id {}'.format(i))
        return db_data

    @staticmethod
    async def fake_db_insert(item):
        # Fake some DB insert
        logger.debug('Starting fake db insertion with id {}'.format(item))
        st = randint(1, 101) / 100
        await asyncio.sleep(st)
        logger.debug('Finished db insertion with id {}, sleep {}'.format(item, st))
        return item

    def loop_start(self):
        logger.info('Starting the loop.')
        if self.__daemon is not None:
            raise Exception
        self.__daemon_terminate = False
        self.__daemon = threading.Thread(target=self.__daemon_main)
        self.__daemon.daemon = True
        self.__daemon.start()

    def loop_stop(self):
        logger.info('Stopping the loop.')
        if self.__daemon is None:
            raise Exception
        self.__daemon_terminate = True
        if threading.current_thread() != self.__daemon:
            self.__daemon.join()
            self.__daemon = None
            logger.debug('Stopped the loop and closed the event_loop.')

    def __daemon_main(self):
        logger.info('Background daemon started (inside __daemon_main).')
        event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)
        run, rc = True, 0
        while run:
            logger.info('Inside \"while run\".')
            event_loop.run_until_complete(self.__cor_main())
            if self.__daemon_terminate:
                event_loop.close()
                run = False
                rc = 1
        return rc

    async def __cor_main(self):
        # If nothing in the queue release control for a bit
        if self.__queue.qsize() == 0:
            logger.info('Event queue is empty, going to sleep (inside __cor_main).')
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            return
        # Extract all items from event queue
        items = self.__queue.get()
        # Run asynchronously DB extraction and processing on the ids (using pool of processes)
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            cors = [self.__cor_process(item, executor) for item in items]
            logger.debug('Launching {} coroutines to elaborate queue items (inside __cor_main).'.format(len(items)))
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(cors)
            logger.debug('Finished to execute __cor_main with result {}, pending {}'
                         .format([t.result() for t in done], pending))

    async def __cor_process(self, item, executor):
        # Extract corresponding DB data
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        db_task = event_loop.create_task(self.fake_db_access(item))
        db_data = await db_task
        # Heavy processing of data done in different processes
        logger.debug('Launching processes to elaborate db_data.')
        res = await event_loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(self.fake_processing, db_data, None))
        return res

    @staticmethod
    async def fake_db_access(item):
        # Fake some db access
        logger.debug('Starting fake db access with id {}'.format(item))
        st = randint(1, 301) / 100
        await asyncio.sleep(st)
        logger.debug('Finished db access with id {}, sleep {}'.format(item, st))
        return item

    @staticmethod
    def fake_processing(db_data, _):
        # fake some CPU processing
        logger.debug('Starting fake processing with data {}'.format(db_data))
        st = randint(1, 101) / 10
        time.sleep(st)
        logger.debug('Finished fake processing with data {}, sleep {}, process id {}'.format(db_data, st, os.getpid()))
        return db_data


def main():
    # Event queue
    queue = SetQueue()
    return Asynchro(event_queue=queue)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = main()
    a.fake_populate(20)
    time.sleep(5)
    a.loop_start()
    time.sleep(20)
    a.loop_stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the reason for running multiple event loops?

I suggest just using the single loop in main thread, it's a native mode for asyncio.

asyncio *might* run loop in non-main thread in very rare scenarios but it doesn't look like your case.

Comment: Thread "A" is generated by mqtt module (in the real code) and needs to be able to call coroutines (e.g., "worker_cor")...this requires an event loop in the thread.
At the same time, Thread "B" is a background daemon that checks the event queue...needs to send coroutines when the queue is not empty...another loop!The main thread would need, in the real code, to launch some db coroutine...a third loop! How could I use just one event loop with these threads? Could you show me by modifying the sample code what would be your solution (indeed one loop means no problem with motor)

Comment: No further explanations or details? I tried to exploit call_soon_threadsafe to reuse the same loop but I got several problems including:

"Exception in callback None()
handle: <Handle>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable". I am pretty much stucked here.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why you need extra loops. If your code executed inside a loop is blocking -- please don't do it but call `ran_in_executor`. If your library incapsulates loop creation internally -- this is a *very bad* smell. Keep everything inside the main loop -- and create asyncio tasks for long running jobs. That's it.